# Why the hdmi output doesn't work on orange pi one?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drm

I made a small linux distro to use on my projects involving an orange pi one H3, but the HDMI output never works

To know if the device was supported by the linux kernel, i tested another distro (armbian), which worked fine. With that in mind, i tried to change my kernel config based on their, adding every relevant feature, but my version was still not working

I decided to take a look at dmesg after every try, and found that there's one error that i can't get rid of

```
[    0.827899] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1100000.mixer (ops 0xc0851c2c)
[    0.835081] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1c0c000.lcd-controller (ops 0xc084e2dc)
[    0.842821] sun8i-dw-hdmi 1ee0000.hdmi: supply hvcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.851453] sun8i-dw-hdmi 1ee0000.hdmi: Detected HDMI TX controller v1.32a with HDCP (sun8i_dw_hdmi_phy)
[    0.861330] sun8i-dw-hdmi 1ee0000.hdmi: registered DesignWare HDMI I2C bus driver
[    0.869108] sun4i-drm display-engine: bound 1ee0000.hdmi (ops 0xc0851228)
[    0.875927] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    0.882941] [drm] Initialized sun4i-drm 1.0.0 20150629 for display-engine on minor 0
[    0.995934] random: fast init done
[    1.001697] sun4i-drm display-engine: [drm] *ERROR* fbdev: Failed to setup generic emulation (ret=-12)
[    1.013330] lima 1c40000.gpu: gp - mali400 version major 1 minor 1
```

I couldn't find anything useful about this specific error on the internet, and i couldn't find the explanation for the return code on the kernel source, what could i do to try to fix that problem?

I'm using

```
- Linux version 5.8.13 (arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35)
- No modules, no initrd/initramfs
- Machine model: Xunlong Orange Pi One
- U-boot (orangepi_one_defconfig)
```

Comment: I found the error on drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c (line 2192). Going inside the functions, i realized that -12 probably means -ENOMEM, if that's the case, it's being returned by drm_file_alloc on a failed kzalloc

Comment: After debugging, turned out that it wasn't this function, and sometimes randomly i get other error instead ([drm] cannot find any crtc or sizes), which i can fix by hardcoding a size (and successfully managing to make the hdmi output work), but i don't know what makes it appear instead of the error i described before, this happens only on some reboots, but i remember appearing more often when i tried to use modules

Comment: I noticed that the "crtc or sizes" error was consistent with the TV turned off, and it always worked if i hardcoded the resolution and turned the device before the tv. I was thinking about using it like that, but because of this, i noticed as well that, if i hardcode my TV max resolution (4K), it didn't work with same error as before.The error was truly ENOMEM due to the high resolution, and i will try to figure out how the armbian kernel config manages to work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is an ENOMEM (out of memory error), because CMA size needs to be bigger than one raw frame of the resolution that the display will use

1920x1080 32bpp needs about 8MB, and the default is 16MB so it was working, but 3840x2160 32bpp needs a bit more than 32MB

Armbian changes the default size to 128M on the kernel configuration, using `CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES=128`

But setting CMA size to 64M with the bootarg `cma=64M`, made it work without any patch or change in configuration

Comment: That was also the solution for me. Thanks for that answer. I would not have found it on my own. Although I first needed to enable in the kernel config CMA at all. (Running OpenWrt on Xunlog Orange Pi Plus 2.) *Now* only *I need to figure out how to force-set a video mode (and have it honoured ...) because the EDID of my display is lying. That was the only reason at all to compile in the GPU based framebuffer driver and not sticking with simplefb, which just takes and uses the framebuffer that was set up before Linux boot.*